# apksigner verify with no output

Tags: android, apk, adb, apksigner

Shouldn't I expect an "Ok" output whenever I run `apksigner verify APK.apk` on my apk and it finishes correctly?

I ran the command on an apk and it simply finished without throwing any warning or message.

I am suspicious that the apk is corrupt because adb install is taking forever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default apksigner does only output warnings and errors on console.

If the verification fails you will see the output `DOES NOT VERIFY`. And the process exit code will be 1 instead of 0 (on Windows this code is stored in `%erorlevel%` on Linux/Bash see `$?`).

If you want to see verification details execute

```
apksigner verify --verbose APK.apk
```

You will get a complete verification result and a separate output for each verification check like this:

```
Verifies
Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): true
Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): true
Verified using v3 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3): false
Verified using v4 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v4): false
Verified for SourceStamp: false
Number of signers: 1
```

I recommend to additionally also output the signing certificate hashes:

```
apksigner verify --print-certs --verbose APK.apk
```

How to estimate the authenticity of the used signing certificate is e.g. included in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218161/2241).