# Getting error while extracting SHA keys from the APK in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, apk, sha

I want to get SHA key to upload on firebase. I am using the following command

```
keytool -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

but getting this following exception

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available
java.io.IOException: Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available
        at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2167)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:222)
        at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1479)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1058)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:405)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:398)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available
        at java.base/javax.crypto.Mac.getInstance(Mac.java:191)
        at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2145)
        ... 5 more
```

Flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.12, on Deepin 20.9 5.15.77-amd64-desktop, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2023.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

OS : Linux Deepin Version 20

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Linux Deepin Version 20 @Davis

Comment: If you have a signed APK you can use `apksigner` for Android SDK:  `apksigner verify --print-certs --verbose APK.apk` see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72189238/150978

Answer (score 0):

Cd into your android folder in your terminal and run `./gradlew signingReport`

```
$cd android
android$ ./gradlew signingReport
```

Comment: graglew is not present under Android. Can't find it.

Comment: It should be there...as `gradlew` not graglew

Comment: I did it. It says 'bash: gradlew: command not found'

Comment: Oh so you use bash? So do this `./gradlew signingReport` in your command line

Comment: Now it saying

"Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "/home/user/.android/debug.keystore": Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available"