# Updated my Android app to target Android 13. It fails to install the updated app unless I delete the older app from my device. Can this be avoided?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I cannot reproduce this problem without rolling back my internal test, but I am wondering if this is a problem or relatively common. My app update failed to install. I deleted the original app from my phone, and then the updated app installed successfully.

How can I analyze this and figure out if this is a hard requirement for all users of my app? Is it problematic that I am still using APKs (my app is grand-fathered in to still allow APK updates)?

Comment: If an update fails but a clean installation works most likely the signature keys have been changed. Most likely the problem is the same as in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76610787/150978